# Tagging Value to recorded lap details

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am trying to figure out how to add on the value of the selected input button into the textarea.

This is my input button to call the action:

```
<a href="javascript:addHTD();" onClick="marklapH()"><input type="button" id="scorebutton" value="TD"></a>
<a href="javascript:addHPT();" onClick="marklapH()"><input type="button" id="scorebutton" value="PAT" name="PAT"></a>
<a href="javascript:addHSF();" onClick="marklapH()"><input type="button" id="scorebutton" value="SFTY" name="Safety"></a>
```

When each of the button is selected, the following javascript runs, respectively:

```
function addHTD(){document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML,10) +6;}
function addHPT(){document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML ++;}
function addHSF(){document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML,10) +2;}
```

Then the score is recorded, adding 6, 1, and 2. But it is recorded in a textarea:

```
<td width="220px"><textarea class="lap" id="Hlapdetails"></textarea></td>
```

With this javascript running:

```
function marklapH()
         {
         if(runningstate == 1)
               {
               if(lapdate != '')
                   {
                    var lapold = lapdate.split(':');
                    var lapnow = stopwatch.value.split(':');
                    var lapcount = new Array();
                    var x = 0
    for(x; x < lapold.length; x++)
         {
     lapcount[x] = new Array();
     lapcount[x][0] = lapold[x]*1;
     lapcount[x][1] = lapnow[x]*1;
          }
     if(lapcount[1][1] < lapcount[1][0])
          {
        lapcount[1][1] += 60;
          lapcount[0][1] -= 1;
         }
      if(lapcount[2][1] < lapcount[2][0])
         {
         lapcount[2][1] += 10;
         lapcount[1][1] -= 1;
          }
     }
   lapdate = stopwatch.value;
   Hlapdetails.value += (++lapcounter) + '. ' + stopwatch.value + '\n';
    }
 }
```

My question is how can I get the TD, PAT, and SFTY to be recorded with the marking of time in the textarea. To look like so:

> 1. 0:24 TD
> 2. 0:35 PAT
>      etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do you want this

```
function addHTD(element)
{
    document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML=(parseInt(document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML,10) +6)+element.value;
}
function addHPT(element)
{
document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML= (document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML+1)+element.value;

}
function addHSF(element)
{
document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML=(parseInt(document.getElementById("HScore").innerHTML,10) +2)+element.value;
 }
```

to make above work you will need to modify html like this

```
<a href="javascript:addHTD(this);" onClick="marklapH()"><input type="button" id="scorebutton" value="TD"></a>
<a href="javascript:addHPT(this);" onClick="marklapH()"><input type="button" id="scorebutton" value="PAT" name="PAT"></a>
<a href="javascript:addHSF(this);" onClick="marklapH()"><input type="button" id="scorebutton" value="SFTY" name="Safety"></a>
```

Comment: Rahul, it's not working actually. But I think from your example it looks like it'll add the value onto the main view and now the textarea, am I correct? I am a newbie in javascript but I have learned a lot recently to understand how certain things are working. So if you could explain further on your example that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Rahul, thanks for updating that. When I input your coding, the marklap marks the "lap" when clicked on but the score itself does not change. I appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 0):

I bascially did the next best thing. I copied the marklap three times and then changed the function names and the outcome to match each selection. and this works.

Thanks for all of your help.